# How do you clear a slice in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

What is the appropriate way to clear a slice in Go?

Here's what I've found in the [go forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/qlUKjMIS9sM):

```
// test.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    fmt.Println(cap(letters))
    fmt.Println(len(letters))
    // clear the slice
    letters = letters[:0]
    fmt.Println(cap(letters))
    fmt.Println(len(letters))
}
```

Is this correct?

To clarify, the buffer is cleared so it can be reused.

An example is [Buffer.Truncate](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Truncate) function in the bytes package.

Notice that Reset just calls Truncate(0). So it appears that in this case line 70 would evaluate:
    b.buf = b.buf[0 : 0]

http://golang.org/src/pkg/bytes/buffer.go

```
// Truncate discards all but the first n unread bytes from the buffer.
60  // It panics if n is negative or greater than the length of the buffer.
61  func (b *Buffer) Truncate(n int) {
62      b.lastRead = opInvalid
63      switch {
64      case n < 0 || n > b.Len():
65          panic("bytes.Buffer: truncation out of range")
66      case n == 0:
67          // Reuse buffer space.
68          b.off = 0
69      }
70      b.buf = b.buf[0 : b.off+n]
71  }
72  
73  // Reset resets the buffer so it has no content.
74  // b.Reset() is the same as b.Truncate(0).
75  func (b *Buffer) Reset() { b.Truncate(0) }
```

Comment: A quick test on: http://play.golang.org/p/6Z-qDQtpbg seems to suggest that it will work (won't change the capacity but it will truncate the length)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It all depends on what is your definition of 'clear'. One of the valid ones certainly is:

```
slice = slice[:0]
```

But there's a catch. If slice elements are of type T:

```
var slice []T
```

then enforcing `len(slice)` to be zero, by the above "trick",  *doesn't* make any element of

```
slice[:cap(slice)]
```

eligible for garbage collection. This might be the optimal approach in some scenarios. But it might also be a cause of "memory leaks" - memory not used, but potentially reachable (after re-slicing of 'slice') and thus not garbage "collectable".

Comment: Interesting. Is there any other way to remove all elements from the underlying array of the slice while leaving the underlying capacity unchanged?

Comment: @ChrisWeber: just iterate over the underlying array and set all the elements to a new value

Comment: @jnml, I do want to reuse the slice (and the underlying array storage) so I'm not constantly allocating a new slice (with array). I've edited my question to clarify and to show some example code from the standard library.

Comment: I'm new to Go. Could you please explain more on why this can be an optimal approach please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the slice size reset cause memory leaks? I am not able to reproduce it

Comment: To clarify a few basic points here, 1. Unlike assigning to nil this does not require garbage collecting/reallocating the memory at all thus depends on the use case it can be faster; 2. It's not a real memory leak in the sense that you can still free it (by assigning it to nil), but if you don't use it properly the program will consume the memory while you don't really need it

Answer (score 254):

Setting the slice to `nil` is the best way to clear a slice.  `nil` slices in go are perfectly well behaved and setting the slice to `nil` will release the underlying memory to the garbage collector.

[See playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pS9QneHRb0)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func dump(letters []string) {
    fmt.Println("letters = ", letters)
    fmt.Println(cap(letters))
    fmt.Println(len(letters))
    for i := range letters {
        fmt.Println(i, letters[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    dump(letters)
    // clear the slice
    letters = nil
    dump(letters)
    // add stuff back to it
    letters = append(letters, "e")
    dump(letters)
}
```

Prints

```
letters =  [a b c d]
4
4
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
letters =  []
0
0
letters =  [e]
1
1
0 e
```

Note that slices can easily be aliased so that two slices point to the same underlying memory.  The setting to `nil` will remove that aliasing.

This method changes the capacity to zero though.

Comment: Nick thanks of the response. Please see my update it you would. I'm clearing the slice for reuse. So I don't necessarily want that the underlying memory released to the GC as I'll just have to allocate it again.

Comment: it is what I searched!)

Comment: Based on the title "How do you clear a slice in Go?" this is by far and away the safer answer and should be the accepted one. A perfect answer would be the combination of the originally accepted answer and this one so people can decide for themselves, though.

Comment: `append`ing to a `nil` slice has always worked in Go?

Comment: @alediaferia ever since go 1.0 certainly.

Comment: Is that nil technique only for slices or will it work for maps too? Nil a map, and then reuse it again later by adding/creating new map entry in the now empty map.

Comment: Side note: A: *'[...] will release the underlying memory [...]'* vs. Q: *'[...] so it can be reused'* – if I read the question right, re-allocation, as necessary after setting to nil, should have been avoided?

Comment: Note: the result of nil slices and empty slices will be different in JSON marshaling

Answer (score 21):

Go 1.21 introduces a [new builtin keyword](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/498755/3/doc/go1.21.html): [`clear()`](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Clear)

[issue 56351](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56351) includes the [following documentation](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/467755/8/doc/go_spec.html#7186):

> The built-in function `clear` takes an argument of map, slice or type parameter type, and deletes or zeroes out all elements.
>
> | Call | Argument type | Result > |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `clear(m)` | `map[K]T` | deletes all entries, resulting in an empty `map (len(m) == 0)` |
> | `clear(s)` | `[]T` | sets all elements up to the length of `s` to the zero value of `T` |
> | `clear(t)` | type parameter | see below > |
>
> If the argument type is a type parameter, all types in its type set must be maps or slices, and `clear` performs the operation corresponding to the actual type argument.
>
> If the map or slice is `nil`, `clear` is a no-op.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking into this issue a bit for my own purposes; I had a slice of structs (including some pointers) and I wanted to make sure I got it right; ended up on this thread, and wanted to share my results.

To practice, I did a little go playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/9i4gPx3lnY

which evals to this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Blah struct {
    babyKitten int
    kittenSays *string
}

func main() {
    meow := "meow"
    Blahs := []Blah{}
    fmt.Printf("Blahs: %v\n", Blahs)
    Blahs = append(Blahs, Blah{1, &meow})
    fmt.Printf("Blahs: %v\n", Blahs)
    Blahs = append(Blahs, Blah{2, &meow})
    fmt.Printf("Blahs: %v\n", Blahs)
    //fmt.Printf("kittenSays: %v\n", *Blahs[0].kittenSays)
    Blahs = nil
    meow2 := "nyan"
    fmt.Printf("Blahs: %v\n", Blahs)
    Blahs = append(Blahs, Blah{1, &meow2})
    fmt.Printf("Blahs: %v\n", Blahs)
    fmt.Printf("kittenSays: %v\n", *Blahs[0].kittenSays)
}
```

Running that code as-is will show the same memory address for both "meow" and "meow2" variables as being the same:

```
Blahs: []
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0c0}]
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0c0} {2 0x1030e0c0}]
Blahs: []
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0f0}]
kittenSays: nyan
```

which I think confirms that the struct is garbage collected. Oddly enough, uncommenting the commented print line, will yield different memory addresses for the meows:

```
Blahs: []
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0c0}]
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0c0} {2 0x1030e0c0}]
kittenSays: meow
Blahs: []
Blahs: [{1 0x1030e0f8}]
kittenSays: nyan
```

I think this may be due to the print being deferred in some way (?), but interesting illustration of some memory mgmt behavior, and one more vote for:

```
[]MyStruct = nil
```

Comment: Nice detailed examples. Thanks!

Comment: This does not show the memory addresses of meo1 and meow2 being the same: `0x1030e0c0` is not equal to `0x1030e0f0` (the former ends in `c0`, the latter in `f0`).

Comment: Got to agree with @carbocation here, those memory addresses are not the same. I don't claim to be able to better explain what's going on here, but this doesn't serve as evidence for me. I do see the same 8-byte discrepancy in the addresses of `meow2` each run...